# Python Tkinter safe to self.quit or sys.exit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

In the spirit of decoupling, rather than cramming many widgets into one giant class, I tried splitting them into separate classes.

The problem I ran into is the FileMenu class does not know about root, and so cannot call root.quit or root.destroy. On a whim I tried self.quit, and it works, but I have not seen this used before.

My questions are:

1. Is self.quit a safe way to quit the app?
2. Is sys.exit a safe way to quit the app?
3. If neither are safe, is there a good way to approach decoupling the design and safely quit without passing root as a parameter everywhere or making it a global?

My example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class FileMenu(tk.Menu):
    def __init__ (self, parent):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent, tearoff=False)
        self.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.quit)

class MainMenu(tk.Menu):
    def __init__ (self, parent):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent, tearoff=False)
        self.file_menu = FileMenu(self)
        self.add_cascade(label='File', menu=self.file_menu)

class View:
    def __init__ (self, parent):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.menu = MainMenu(self.frame)
        self.parent.configure(menu=self.menu)
        self.parent.geometry('200x200')
        self.frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

class App:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.view = View(self.root)

    def run (self):
        self.root.title('Window Title')
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Both use for different purpose:

> **sys.exit()**: Close complete application.
>
> **self.quit**: If you have multiple windows in your application and you don't want to close your whole application then you should use self.quit().
>
> Both are safe to use but uses are different.

Answer (score 1):

If the class doesn't know about the root object but you expect it to act on the root object, you should pass it in.

In `App`, you pass the root object into `View`:

```
self.view = View(self.root)
```

In `View`, you create a `MainMenu` and pass it `self.frame`:

```
self.menu = MainMenu(self.frame)
```

Instead, also pass it the root object:

```
self.menu = MainMenu(self.frame, parent)
```

And make `MainMenu` expect a parameter of that object, and pass it to `FileMenu`:

```
class MainMenu(tk.Menu):
    def __init__ (self, parent, root):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent, tearoff=False)
        self.file_menu = FileMenu(self, root)
        self.add_cascade(label='File', menu=self.file_menu)
```

Then make `FileMenu` expect a parameter of that root object. Now it has access to it:

```
class FileMenu(tk.Menu):
    def __init__ (self, parent, root):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent, tearoff=False)
        self.add_command(label='Exit', command=root.destroy)
```

And you can use the Tkinter root object's `destroy` method to quit the application properly.